# Flutter Windows firebase_firestore.lib\_absl_int128.dir_Debug_int128.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc_dbg\

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, android-studio, flutter-windows

i tried to run this command in android studio terminal:

> flutter build windows

but then it showed this error:

> firebase_firestore.lib(66531b215daa3d3cdf2fac8071e89a00_absl_int128.dir_Debug_int128.obj)
> : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc_dbg
> [D:\APPS\eaziprep_app_desktop\build\windows\x64\runner\eaziprep_app_desktop.vcxproj]

i tried so many ways to resolve it like made a new flutter project and also ran **flutter clean** command but nothing worked and it shows at the end **building failed**